# Multi inject with constructor parameter from a property of another dependency with Ninject

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, ninject

I have an interface with an enumeration of instances implementing IModule interface:

```cs
public interface IConfiguration
{
    IEnumerable<IModule> Modules { get; }
}
```

I have a class that takes IModule implementation as a constructor parameter:

```cs
public class ModuleClient : IModuleClient
{
    public ModuleClient(IModule module)
    {
    }
}
```

I also have a class taking an array of IModuleClient implementations as a constructor parameter:

```cs
public class ModuleService : IModuleService
{
    public ModuleService(IModuleClient[] clients)
    {

    }
}
```

I need to create an array of IModuleClient instances with each of the IModule instances from Modules property and inject the array into ModuleService constructor.

Is it somehow possible to achieve this with multi injection or do I have to create a factory of IModuleClient instances and inject it along with IConfiguration into ModuleService?

I can access the kernel from the context and e.g. bind constructor parameter to a property of another interface the following way:

```cs
Bind<IModuleClient>()
    .To<ModuleClient>()
    .WithConstructorArgument("module", c => c.Kernel.Get<IConfiguration>().Module);
```

```cs
public interface IConfiguration
{
    IModule Module { get; }
}
```

```cs
public class ModuleClient : IModuleClient
{
    public ModuleClient(IModule module)
    {
    }
}
```

[Multi injection](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/wiki/Multi-injection) allows binding multiple implementations to a single interface and get an array of interface implementations injected. Can I bind several instances with different constructor parameters to an interface and inject it as an array?

One possible solution is creating IModuleClient factory, injecting it with IConfiguration to ModuleService and creating instances using the factory. I am wondering is there a easier or better solution?

Comment: 1) who creates the Foo instance ?  
(And don't say the container .. I mean who gets an IFoo injected to it) or who resolves an IFoo instance.

2) is Foo suppose to be a singleton or some how scoped to an instance of Baz ?

Comment: If you want any useful answers, you might want to update your question and give more context about what you are doing and why. Please use real class and interface names, possibly describe what classes are intended to contain or do, and describe why you actually need or want this. This allows others to give feedback on the design and suggest alternative designs that make your problem either easier, or possibly even go away completely.

Comment: @eranotzap Foo is actually created using a factory, which parses a configuration file and creates an interface proxy containing configuration values. The configuration is injected into configuration service, which provides an interface to validate and to save the configuration. IFoo is in singleton scope.

Comment: @Steven thanks for the advice. I wanted to keep the question simple but I guess it makes sense to provide more information. I will update the question.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried either of these approaches, but theoretically you could apply `ModuleClient` bindings for each of the `Modules`:

```
var config = kernel.Get<IConfiguration>();
foreach(var module in config.Modules)
    kernel.Bind<IModuleClient>()
        .To<Module>()
        .WithConstructorArgument("module", module);
```

... or you could probably just create a binding for the array itself:

```
Bind<IModuleClient[]>()
   .To(c => c.Kernel.Get<IConfiguration>().Modules
       .Select(m => new ModuleClient(m))
       .ToArray());
```

Comment: AFAIK array binding (as well as `IList<T>`, and `IEnumerable<T>`) will not work as ninject's "multi injection" feature will basically take over resolution before the binding is ever checked.

Comment: @BatteryBackupUnit: Thanks for that feedback. I'd never used multi injection, so I wasn't sure how that would work.